# How to assign 0 and 1 to a decision variable based on other decision variables in OPL

Tags: conditional-statements, variable-assignment, opl

I am using IBM ILOG CPLEX. I have a binary decision variable zbt[b][t]. Now I need to assign 0 or 1 to it depending if the below condition is satisfied

sum(b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, m in Plants, t in TimePeriods) ( Xbimt[b][i][m][t])
  + sum( b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, s in Stockpiles, t in TimePeriods)(Xbist[b][i][s][t]) >= oreTons[b]

Xbimt , Xbist, are decision variables and float oreTons[b] are float

I tried

if (sum(b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, m in Plants, t in TimePeriods) ( Xbimt[b][i][m][t])
  + sum( b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, s in Stockpiles, t in TimePeriods)(Xbist[b][i][s][t]) >= oreTons[b])  {zbt[b][t]:=1} else {zbt[b][t]:=0}    ;

I get several Syntax errors, like expected =, unexpected else

The part I am trying is as below : 
Zbt = 1 if

∑*(i=1)^I▒∑*(m=1)^M▒∑*(t=1)^T▒"Xbimt  +"   ∑*(i=1)^I▒∑*(s=1)^S▒∑*(t=1)^T▒"Xbist  >0 " 
And Zbt = 0 otherwise

Comment: Adding to the above post by me :         Even if something like the below worked it would be helpful.  But this also gives error.                                                                                                                                     xyz = sum(b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, m in Plants, t in TimePeriods)  Xbimt[b][i][m][t] +
  sum( b in PitBlocks, i in PitExits, s in Stockpiles, t in TimePeriods) Xbist[b][i][s][t];

forall(b in PitBlocks, t in TimePeriods )
  {
if (xyz >= oreTons[b])  {zbt[b][t]==1;} else {zbt[b][t]==0;}      
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use decision variables in the condition of an `if` (this is stated explicitly in the documentation). To model your constraint you can use logical constraints, in particular the implies operator:

```
expression => expression
```

In your case for example

```
(sum (...) ... >= oreTons[b]) => (decision_variable == 1)
```

That forces `decision_variable` to 1 in case the condition on the left of the operator is satisfied.